# why is const being flagged as a syntax error in this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn to use appium, and running their tutorial test code:

```
const wdio = require('webdriverio');

const opts = {
  port: 4723,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "Android",
    platformVersion: "8.0",
    deviceName: "Android Emulator",
    app: "C:\Users\SStaple\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/ApiDemos-debug.apk",
    automationName: "UiAutomator2"
  }
};

const client = wdio.remote(opts);
client
  .init()
  .click("~App")
  .click("~Alert Dialogs")
  .back()
  .back()
  .end();
```

All I get from running this code is Syntax error in Line:1 Char:1.
I thought const was legal Javascript.
What is going on here?

I am running the code from the Command prompt. I hacve installed the Webdriver in the same folder as the Javascript file.

Comment: "All I get from running this code" — How, exactly, are you running the code? Where does the error message appear?

Comment: "I am running the code from the Command prompt" — How? What command are you using? Through what software? What version of that software?

Comment: It is still unclear what you are trying right now. Did you just copy and paste that into your Windows command prompt? That's not how it works.

Comment: @Quentin. The command prompt is that which is run by typing cmd in the Run dialog! To run my code, I just type the filename, in this inst appiumTest.js ?!?

Comment: @E_net4 - I put the code in a file, as usual ?!?

Comment: I guess you haven't read this line in the tutorial, `"You can try and run this test on your own. Simply save it and execute it using node."`

Answer (score 3):

Your JS file is not a Windows executable, nor is it a script that the Windows command prompt can interpret.

You need to run it using a JavaScript runtime. The most popular one is [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/).

```
node appiumTest.js
```